# Crash when deleting cell values Worksheet_Change event

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to run a macro (say test1) continously on a worksheet whenever the value in a given range (F5 to LastRow). The Worksheet_Activate and Worksheet_Change event helped in this respect. However, Excel crashes whenever the values in the range are deleted. As example:

F5 = 100, F6 = 120,F7 = 140

Suppose the value of F5 is changed to 120. Then the macro and events are working fine. However, when all the values are deleted (so F5 uptill F7 are empty), Excel crashes.

I have tried to run each line in my code seperately, but I am not sure what is causing the crash (perhaps the loop as written in the macro)?

I am a beginner with VBA and any assistance is much appreciated :-)

```
Sub TEST()

 Dim LastRow As Long
 Dim i As Long

 LastRow = Sheets("blad1").Range("F5").End(xlDown).Row

 For i = 5 To LastRow

 Range("Z" & i).Formula = "=ABS(F" & i & " -(J" & i & " *(100/21)))< 5" 
 'Checks if the value in column F matches the amount in column J for each 
 'cellin that column with a significance of 5. The return is shown as 
 'True or False.
  Next i

 For i = 5 To LastRow

 If Range("Z" & i) = True Then Range("F" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 
 255, 255) Else: Range("F" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 
 'If the 
 'value in column Z is True, then the cell colour in column F is white. 
 'If False, then red.
 Next i

 End Sub

 'These are the lines on the relevant worksheet:

 Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

 Call test

 End Sub

 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 Dim LastRow As Long
 LastRow = Sheets("Test").Range("F5").End(xlDown).Row

 If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F5:F" & LastRow)) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Call test
    Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: Are these in the same module? If so, the `Range` doesn't seem to match - you're referring to `Sheets("blad1")` in `Sub TEST()`, but the change handler implies that the code is in `Sheets("Test")`.

Comment: Sorry, I had mistyped this when putting the code on this post. The sheet name is actually blad1. When executing the code in Excel the worksheetnames were equal to eachother.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
LastRow = Sheets("blad1").Range("F5").End(xlDown).Row
```

is returning a value equal to the **absolute very last row possible** (1048576) when column F is empty. The rest of your macro is then iterating through the entire sheet executing your code for every single row. You can imagine what happens when you try to insert 1048572 formulas into a spreadsheet. A better option would be to use

```
LastRow = Sheets("blad1").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

To get the last used row searching from the bottom up. Then you could change your `Worksheet_Change` logic to

```
If LastRow > 1 Then
    'Code Here
End if
```

**EDIT:**

Also worth noting, when `LastRow = Sheets("blad1").Range("F5").End(xlDown).Row` then this code

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F5:F" & LastRow)) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Call test
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
```

will always evaluate `True` when you're editing values in Column F at any row number greater than row 4 because `Intersect()` basically says "If Range one and Range two overlap return true". So, `Range("F7")` is within `Range("F5:F1048576")` regardless of whether or not it has a value.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I will try this. Just for my understanding, is Rows.Count only selecting the cells in the range which have a value stored within? Or will it also count empty cells? basically I would like to run the macro automatically, but only when the cell value is not empty.

Comment: `Rows.Count` returns the total number of rows possible in excel. It doesn't select anything. The following parameters after are what specifies the search direction `.End(xlUp)` or `.End(xlDown)`. The latter will return a numeric value for the last populated cell from the top down, the former will return a numeric value for the first populated cell from the bottom up. Lets say you have `F5` and `F10` populated. `xlDown` would return `5`, `xlUp` would return `10`. If no cells are populated `xlDown` will return `1048576`, `xlUp` will return `1`.

Comment: It's worth noting that the search starts at the range specified before the `xlDown/xlUp` parameters. That is to say, with `F5` and `F10` populated, `Range("F1").End(xlDown)` would return `5` and `Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` would return `10`. For your purpose, using `Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` makes the most sense and will keep your excel application from crashing.

Comment: Thank you again; I understand setting the range now and the code prevented the Excel file from crashing.